# Object fixed below certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my first post here, before this I have had tremendous help from this forum and all the users previous posts. The question I have now I cannot find the answer to. So:

I have an object (button) which when pressed smoothscrolls the user up to top of the page. Im successful in making it fixed to the top of the screen, however, lets say youre at the bottom of the page and you press the "smoothscroll button", its starts scrolling you upwards to the top. But when your "near" the top I want the button to stop and the scrolling to continue...

Im not sure how to describe it better, but if you go from the top of the page, or when at the top of the page, you dont see the button and when you start scrolling down, youll see the button as any object on the screen "climbing upwards" and when the button reaches the top of the screen it stays there fixed.

Im sure this is common on ads for example..

How would you achieve this? Any help appreciated..

Thx,

Layman

Comment: What, if anything, have you tried? Can you show us some code?

Comment: see this website it has great demo

http://www.onlywebpro.com/2013/04/03/make-a-jquery-sticky-header-in-5-minutes/

Comment: So.... did any answer help you or what???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is what you want to achieve.

http://stickyjs.com/

if you are still not impressed.. here is a link to the treasure of plugins that would do what you need with very little code.

http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/sticky-scroll

Answer (score 0):

One of my coworkers wrote a plugin that hides a button as the page is being scrolled to the top. You may be able to use similar logic. It would be something like this:

```
btt.revealPosition = 300;
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= btt.revealPosition){
            //Add a class here that lets the button scroll with the page
        }else{
            //Add a class here that fixes the button to the top of the page

        }
    });
```

It basically watches the scroll position as you're scrolling back to the top of the page. Upon reaching the revealPosition of the button, you could add a class or modify the css with jquery to change how the button is acting.

This logic was taken from the following plugin:
[jquery-backtotop](https://github.com/stepframe/jquery-backtotop)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Im sure if I knew more about js i could have made something out of this plugin. But I need finals at this stage :)