# How to code a div to be fixed while rest of content is scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

My new home page has a position fixed header at the top of the page and the container holding the content scrolls up underneath that.

Theres a text box that on the left which I want to fix so that its always visible when the rest of the content scrolls up.

The container which holds all copy is positioned relative with auto margins so that it sits central onscreen.

I haven't been able to find code online that will enable me to keep the div in the container and therefore obey the central alignment of the container, but be fixed below the header while the rest of the container scrolls.

Any ideas how I could do this please? Is it javascript or CSS?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried putting the text box and header in one div together, but then the content gets pushed down. I read that floating should work but doesn't. I have looked at 'sticking' the text box to the bottom of the header div, but can't seem to get that to work.

See [www.broadleydesign.co.uk/test3](http://www.broadleydesign.co.uk/test3)

NB. Apologies if the header isn't stuck at the top in IE on your machine; I haven't sorted any workaround yet. There should be a white space at the top with the logo and top links in. The images should scroll up underneath that. I haven't got a pc to check it!

Comment: Please paste the relevant parts of your HTML/CSS/JS code here. It would also be helpful to make a jsfiddle. Also you could make a small sketch to explain, what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `ul` into the head section and give it `position: fixed` css, not `position: absolute`. See my example below using your code:

```
<div id="header-cont">
        <h1><img src="images/background/logo.jpg" alt="Broadley Design, Graphic design and image production"></h1>

    <div id="home">
        <ul id="titles">
            <li><a href="index.html" class="active">home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="profile.html">profile</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="sideheads">
            <li class="firstsub">
                <img src="images/headings/broadley_design_co.png" alt="">
            </li>
            <li><span class="bold"> Diane Broadley</span> 
            </li>
            <ul class="sublistwider">
                <li>A freelance graphic designer specialising in print, providing a one
                    <br>to one service, design solutions and production to ensure that your business gets into the hands of the people who
                    <br>matter to you.</li>
                <li>Working both directly with small businesses, designers and publishers
                    <br>in the South West.</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the `position:fixed` css property to the target div.

```
<div class="fixed">Fixed Text</div>
```

and style it as:

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/dwA3Q/)

Answer (score 0):

I have suggested a jQuery(javascript) plugin [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22076023/object-fixed-below-certain-point/22076445#22076445)

There are various JQuery plugins that can help you do what you want.
This functionality is called as "sticky scroll"